# If $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 21= 2\cdot (a + 2b + 4c)$, with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$, what's the value of $abc$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, here's how it goes. I'm totally fascinated on solving some peruvian books I bought (just for fun) and I've staggered on this one problem, described in the title.

If I use the fact that $(a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ac)$, it makes me go nowhere, since there's no way to correlate $(a + 2b + 4c)$ with the double letter term between the parentheses.

I'm out of clues. Anyone caring to help?

Comment: There is only one real value of $a, b, c$ possible. Get it in the form $(a-a_1)^2 + (b-b_1)^2 + (c-c_1)^2 = 0$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

You can rewrite your equation like this $$(a^2-2a) + (b^2-4b) +(c^2-8c) = -21$$

Do you notice anything familiar in brackets?

Answer (score 2):

So $a^2 + b^2 +C^2 +1 +4 + 16 - 2a -4b -8c = 0 $
therefore we have $ (a-1)^2 + (b-2)^2 + (c-4)^2 = 0$
Some of sum non-negative numbers is Zero, so all of them are zero, hence:
$a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=4$. Therefore $abc=8$.